# Next.js 13.4 Parallel/intercepting routes inside route group gives error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Here is my folder structure

[image]

I was following nextjs [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes#modals) to make modal as their nextgram example, I list items on feedback route when i hit one of them it should be routing local/feedback to local/product/slug yet it gives multiple errors like this

> Warning: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`Router`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Router`, follow the stack trace as described in

> Uncaught TypeError: initialTree is not iterable

> The above error occurred in the  component:at Router

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 9):

You can remove the .next folder and reload your app, it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

After lot of debugging, the only thing that worked was removing the .next folder and restarting the dev server. Everything will work as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Simply restarting the dev server worked for me, I did not have to remove the `.next` folder.